# Google Maps Android API v2 - Map is not showing

Tags: android

I need your help. I can't make a functioning Map on Android. I get only the two zoom-in and zoom-out buttons, but the map itself is not visible, not even the grid.
I have also checked the other similar questions, but they helped me only a little.

I have instaled the Google API, made a Support Library, have an API key, have had the permissions as described in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start. 
When I use:
    
I get only the zoom buttons. Do you know how to sove this?
And do you happen to know why if I use MapFragment I get the  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #95: Error inflating class fragment exception?

Comment: Sorry, this did't show:

Comment: <fragment
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

Comment: Is it just showing grey behind the buttons?

Comment: @Matt. Hi Matt. It is not showing anything. Just white. and the buttons.

Comment: I have solved the problem. There were problems with the API Key from Google API Console. It was not good. This was why the map was not loading. There were problems with the package name which was used when generating the API key.

Comment: I deleted the android wrong API key and made a new good one.

Answer (score 1):

last week I had the same problem as yours. Did you go at Google API console, and checked  the "Google Maps Android API v2" as "on"? After that, mine one started to work.

Sorry for my terrible English.